# Are Apache 2.0- and MIT-licensed components open source?

Tags: mit, apache-2.0

I am using a software with components marked as Apache 2.0 and MIT license. Are they considered as open source components, also are they redistributable?

Answer (score 3):

The Free Software Foundation [lists](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#GPLCompatibleLicenses) both Apache2 and the X11 (often called MIT) licences as being both free and GPL-compatible.  The OSI [lists](https://opensource.org/licenses/alphabetical) both licences as meeting their definition of Open Source.  So by the usual standards, content offered under either of those licences is both free and open-source.

> are they redistributable

The FSF's four freedoms include the freedom to distribute copies of the software, and the OSI's open-source definition requires free redistributability.  Both licences have some small requirements that you must honour, mostly to do with preservation of copyright notices, but as long as you honour those, then yes, the content is freely-redistributable.